# C# Serial Port Read - Get COBS coded messages with different lenght

Tags: c#, serial-port

so im new in C# Programming. I have programmed a C# Forms Application in Visual Studio to communicate to/initialze a device over the Serial Port. The communication between the device is COBS coded, so there are no 0x00 bytes except on the end of each message. The messages sent and received have different length.

My problem is at the moment, that the Messages I receive are not complete or start at the middle of a message, so i cannot trigger sent messages on a specific value in the received messages. You can determine end of a message with received 0x00 (0x00 means end of message in COBS coded data)

So what i need is something to handle the complete message and put it in a byte array to analyze i.e. byte[11] for a specific value.

Here is what ive done so far:

```
    private bool   b_portopen = false;
    private byte[] b_rcv_buffer = new byte[256];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            //InitTimer();

            if (b_portopen == false)
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                serialPort1.Open();
                b_portopen = true;
                button1.Text = "Close";
                button2.Enabled = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Serial Port Opened");
            }
            else if (b_portopen == true)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                b_portopen = false;
                button1.Text = "Open";
                button2.Enabled = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Serial Port Closed");
            }
        }
private async void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Read(b_rcv_buffer, 0, 256);
            //serialPort1.Read(b_rcv_buffer1, 11, 2);
            richTextBox1_receive.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                richTextBox1_receive.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(b_rcv_buffer) + "\n");
                richTextBox1_receive.ScrollToCaret();
            }));
            switch (b_rcv_buffer[10])
            {
                case b_state_startup:
                    do something

                case b_state_be_start_conf:
                    do something

                case b_state_keepalive_conf:
                    do something

                case b_state_unprepare_conf:
                    do something

                case b_state_prepare_conf:
                    do something


            }


        }
```

Comment: Maybe change your DataReceivedHandler to just buffer the incoming data (appending to current buffer) & have a separate thread processing that buffer checking for complete commands & removing the associated data from the buffer. Maybe use something like a thread-safe class like ConcurrentQueue for the buffer so incoming data can be safely added whilst processing the queue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How do you think would be the best way to append the received data? If i use an byte array to fill with incoming data, at some point it will be full and i also cannot cut complete messages from it. So i need to use some kind of dynamic array where i can store plain byte values in and cut them from the start if there is a complete message. Is there some data type like this?

Comment: I did suggested [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) as a possibility - using Enqueue to queue the incoming data byte by byte & using the Contains extension method to search for the 0x00 byte. NOTE there may be better classes to use - this was my first thought as it is thread-safe.

Comment: @PaulF: `ConcurrentQueue` does not provide adequate synchronization between threads for this purpose.  (It synchronizes every byte separately, meaning you can get multiple incoming messages mixed up together in the queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found a solution with using ConcurrentQueue:

```
    ConcurrentQueue<byte> b_rcv_buffer = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();

    private Timer timer2;

    public void InitTimer()
            {
                timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
                timer2.Interval = 1; // in miliseconds
                timer2.Start();
            }

    private async void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buf = new byte[bytes];
            serialPort1.Read(buf, 0, serialPort1.BytesToRead);

            for(int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
            {
                b_rcv_buffer.Enqueue(buf[i]); //Enqueue every received Byte in Concurrentqueue
            }
        }

private async void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (b_rcv_buffer.Contains<byte>(0x00))
            {
                byte[] array = b_rcv_buffer.ToArray();

                richTextBox1_receive.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    richTextBox1_receive.AppendText(BitConverter.ToString(array) + "\n");
                    //richTextBox1_receive.ScrollToCaret();
                }));            

                byte ignored;

                while (b_rcv_buffer.TryDequeue(out ignored));
        }
```

Comment: This is not correct -- if more data is received while the first `Enqueue` loop is running, the `DataReceivedHandler` will run in multiple threads simultaneously and the data buffers will be interleaved. The `DataReceived` event causes nothing but trouble. Just make one `async` loop that calls `await port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(...);`, processes the data, repeat.  That way every buffer is fully processed in the order received. As a bonus, it saves threads, avoids other race conditions, can interact with UI without `InvokeRequired`, doesn't need a `ConcurrentQueue`, and is overall more efficient.